# External monitor image not centered in the screen

Tags: linux, display, xorg, external-display

I'm using Xorg 7.5 on a Radeon HD4870 with the FOSS radeonhd server on my HP 6830s. The laptop has a VGA connector and I attach it to a 37" panasonic plasma TV. It works fine except for a little annoyance: when activated, the TV screen is set to the resolution of 1360x768 (which it reports as being the highest it supports) but all the image is shifted by about 100 pixels to the right. I can't see the leftmost part of the page, and I have a black vertical bar to the right.

If I change the resolution to 1024x768 there is no shifting, the image fills the entire screen with no parts hidden, but at this resolution the image is stretched.

How can I tune the position on the external monitor so that the image is centered in the screen filling it entirely?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the monitor controls to adjust the display? Is would be a case of circumventing the problem rather than solving it, but what the heck...

Comment: I'm seconding @CJM's suggestion.  However, since this is a TV instead of a real monitor, it may not have the necessary controls to adjust the Horizontal and Vertical position of the image that's displayed.  I know all PC monitors (legacy and modern) do, but I don't think TVs do.  May want to check around.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the catalyst control center? I d'ont know if you can ajust the the screen in Linux, but in Windows you can.

Comment: Actually I'm using the free driver, with the proprietary ATI drivers I can't get the external display to work at all.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I don't know how you would make that whitout a control panel :S